# Accessing negative index of vector via operator[] and .at()

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, indexoutofboundsexception

```
vector<int> input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 17, 117, 517, 997};
cout<< "input vector at index -1 is: " << input[-1] <<endl;
```

Using the above the code, the result will be: input at index -1 is: 0. 
However, if we use follwoing :

```
vector<int> input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 17, 117, 517, 997};
cout<< "input vector at index -1 is: " << input.at(-1) <<endl;
```

The result would be :
input at index -1 is: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector.

Can some one explain the reason to me? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `at` member does range-checks and responds appropriately.

The `operator []` does not. This is undefined behavior and a bug in your code.

This is explicitly stated in the docs.

Comment: Could you please tell me what bug could be? It seems for every input vector, its index at -1 is always 0 when I use operator[].

Comment: @FengZhou That is a coincidence that you see a `0` at that position. It is still an illegal statement. You are looking outside the contents of the vector. The content you are not allowed to look at contains a `0`.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah , it is a coincidence I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The first is undefined behavior.  Anything could happen.  You aren't allowed to complain, no matter what happens.

The second, an exception is thrown and you don't catch it, so `std::terminate()` is called and your program dies.  The end.